# How to remove pagination on a carousel in primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

I need to remove the carousel of primeng, but i don't know how to do that

```
 <p-carousel *ngIf="estadoClasificacion"
 [value]="listadoCuentaClasificaciones" [numVisible]="3"
 [numScroll]="3"
       [circular]="false">
       <p-header>
       </p-header>
       <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
         <div class="item-details">
           <div class="p-grid p-nogutter">
             <button pButton type="button" label="{{item.descripcion}}" lass="ui-button-raised carrusel-botones"
               (click)="capturaClasificacion(item)"></button>
           </div>
         </div>
       </ng-template>
     </p-carousel>
```

Comment: Please provide some sample code and mention what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property to use on the Primeng carousel to remove or hide it.But overriding the style class (ui-carousel-dots-container) of the container of the paginator, you will be able to overcome this situation.Please override the style class as below.

Just add this class to your .css or .scss file.

```
.ui-carousel-dots-container{
display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: a pesar de que coloco todo tal cuál (con el !important no funciona). La única forma es ocultando directamente en el carousel.css (aunque no sea buena práctica).

Answer (score 0):

you can hide controls using a little trick with css

```
::ng-deep{
       .p-hide-paginator{
        .p-carousel-indicators{
        display: none !important;
      }
   }
 }


 <p-carousel [value]="items" [ngClass]="!hidePaginator ? 'p-hide-paginator': '' " >
```

Comment: Thank you, helped me like described in my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

José's answer didn't work for me as ::ng-deep is deprecated, but it helped me find a way:

```
 <p-carousel [value]="items" ngClass="hidePaginator">
```

And then in the style.css / style.scss file in the App Folder:

```
.p-hide-paginator{
  .p-carousel-indicators{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

So now the "hidePaginator" Class decides if the carousel is shown with or without pagination.

Answer (score 0):

HTML-Template:

```
<p-carousel [value]="items" styleClass="items-carousel">
```

SCSS:

```
:host ::ng-deep .items-carousel {
  .ui-carousel-dots-container {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Worked for me.